# Tmux commands: What is M-whatever

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

Might be a very silly question to many folks out there, but I'm dense!

Ex:

Applying predefined layouts:

```
C-a M-1        switch to even-horizontal layout
C-a M-2        switch to even-vertical layout
C-a M-3        switch to main-horizontal layout
C-a M-4        switch to main-vertical layout
C-a M-5        switch to tiled layout
C-a space      switch to the next layout
```

What is M? If it's just shift+m then please take away my neckbeard right now.  I thought it might be alt + key but that doesn't seem to be it.

Comment: They are the `Alt` key: so, to switch to tiled layout, you would press `Ctrl-a` `Alt-5`...

Comment: thanks @jasonwryan - that's correct. Now it seems my problem is: why does Alt behave like Alt (and output alternate chars as opposed to doing the tmux command I thought it would)? Which isn't really a problem, but more of a configuration issue at this point.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's the [meta key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key). So M-1 is meta-1. (Just like how C-1 is control-1).

Now, when you look at your keyboard, you probably notice the distinct lack of any key actually labeled meta, at least if you have a normal PC keyboard. Depending on how your keyboard layout is set up, meta is typically either the alt key or the logo (Windows) key.

In short, `C-a M-1` is telling you to press and hold <kbd>Control</kbd> and press <kbd>A</kbd>; then release both; then press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> (or <kbd>Windows</kbd>) and press <kbd>1</kbd>. The release them, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This led down the path of remapping my left option key to act as +Esc in iterm2, which accomplishes the various tmux commands that Meta is meant for.

Comment: Most terminal emulators make two Meta bindings.  First, they will bind `Alt` to `Meta`, allowing `Alt-3` to be parsed as `M-3`.  They will generally also make `Esc` followed by any key act as though you had pressed a Meta key combination.

Comment: I'm now trying tmux on Windows Subsystem for Linux (wsl) and 'meta key' isn't a well known term in the Windows world. All the key binding guides I was reading were assuming I'd know what `M-1` meant. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Years later, I came across [image: this keyboard in a vintage computing museum]

Notice the Meta key to the left and right of the keyboard! Along with a host of other useful keys. I wonder what Rub Out does...

Comment: See https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/495/what-do-the-keys-on-this-symbolics-space-cadet-keyboard-do for what all those keys do.